# Dropdown menu renders underneath incorrect navbar item

Tags: drop-down-menu, alignment, twitter-bootstrap-2

I'm building a site with Bootstrap 2, and I'd like to add a dropdown menu to one item in the navbar.

Simple enough.  However, when the dropdown is expanded, it appears underneath the incorrect item in the navbar:

[image: Dropdown menu expanded underneath leftmost navbar element instead of the dropdown container.]

Notice in the above screenshot that the dropdown renders underneath "Admin" (the leftmost navbar element) instead of "Locator" (the element that activates the dropdown).

How do I fix this so that the dropdown appears underneath the correct navbar element?

Here is the HTML for the navbar:

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="...">Dashboard</a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="...">Admin</a></li>
          <li><a href="...">Find Trips</a></li>

          <!-- Locator Dropdown -->
          <li>
            <a id="nav-locator-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="..."
                   data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
              Locator
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="nav-locator-dropdown">
              <li><a href="...">My Trips</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Create Trip</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="...">My Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="...">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Your dropdown is appearing on the wrong spot because you're missing the class that defines the relative position for your dropdown. To fix this, just add the `.dropdown` class to your menu item with a submenu like so:

`<li class="dropdown"> ... </li>`

Here is your fixed markup:

**HTML**

```
<div class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-top">
  <div class="navbar-inner">
    <div class="container">
      <a class="brand" href="...">Dashboard</a>

      <div class="nav-collapse collapse pull-right">
        <ul class="nav">
          <li><a href="...">Admin</a></li>
          <li><a href="...">Find Trips</a></li>

          <!-- Locator Dropdown -->
          <li class="dropdown">
            <a id="nav-locator-dropdown" class="dropdown-toggle" href="..."
                   data-toggle="dropdown" data-target="#">
              Locator
              <span class="caret"></span>
            </a>
            <ul class="dropdown-menu" role="menu" aria-labelledby="nav-locator-dropdown">
              <li><a href="...">My Trips</a></li>
              <li><a href="...">Create Trip</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>

          <li><a href="...">My Profile</a></li>
          <li><a href="...">Log Out</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```